# How to refresh webView when app receives a message from GCM

Tags: android, webview, google-cloud-messaging

I can receive push notification with the below code successfully

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

Toast toast;

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

public static final String TAG = "GCM";

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
         * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
         * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
        // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            // This loop represents the service doing some work.
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1)
                        + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

            String msg = extras.getString("message");
            sendNotification(msg);
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + msg);

        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

// Put the message into a notification and post it.
// This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
// a GCM message.
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
    .setContentTitle("InnoProperty Notification")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();

     }
   }
```

And app has a webView in MainActivity.

I want to refresh webView when my app receives push message but I don't know how I can find webView in GCMIntentService class.

Comment: try this, when you initialize the GcmIntentService constructor try to pass an argument to it i.e. your webview. Or make a class extending webview and make it public make a static method in it call it in GCMIntentService class.

Comment: XshivDev, Would you post a simple sample code ?

Comment: added some pseudo code

Answer (score 2):

This is not tested, only logic and may have typos

put this is GcmIntentService

```
public GcmIntentService(View yourWebView) { 
    super("GcmIntentService"); 
}
```

Call this constructor when you instantiate GcmIntentService class object.

The another solution i think can work is making a public class

```
public class myWebView extends WebView
{
 // Implement other methods..
..

public static void randomRefresh()
{
 //refresh you browser here
}
}
```

make a global class which extends Application

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application{

    private myWebView name;


    public myWebView getWebview() {

        return name;
    } 

    public void setWebView(myWebView aName) {

       name = aName;

    } 
}
```

just set webview as global and access it anywhere.

i don't know that is this a good implementation but this is all i have.

**EDIT:**

So, I think second solution is better and here is the code

make a class **myWebview**

public class myWebview extends WebView {

```
static WebView mWebView;
public myWebview(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mWebView=this;
}

public static void refreshView()
{
    mWebView.reload();
}
```

}

Create a class **globalclass**

```
public class globalclass extends Application {

    myWebview webview;

    private myWebview name;


    public myWebview getWebview() { 

        return name;
    }  

    public void setWebView(myWebview aName) {

       name = aName;

    } 
}
```

Don't forget to edit android manifest

```
<application
        android:name="com.example.blabla.globalclass"
...
...
...
```

In MainActivity where the webview resides

```
final globalclass globalc = (globalclass) getApplicationContext(); 
        globalc.setWebView(YourWebviewHere);
```

Then in GCMIntentService where you want to refresh

```
final globalclass gc = (globalclass) getApplicationContext();
            gc.getWebview().reload();
```

this is the best i can help to make it understandable.

hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks XshivDev...but it's hard to understand for beginner like me.

Comment: OK, you asked for simple sample code, anyways i will try to make it understandable for a beginner.